# Netbeans and play framework using google web toolkit

Tags: java, gwt, netbeans, playframework

I was given a java project and I was trying to import it into Netbeans using the `netbeansify` command (in play framework). This project uses the gwt framework.  The application runs well using the `play run` command.  When I am trying to run project with netbeans, I am connected to localhost:9000 (the port that the play framework listens to).  The following error message comes up in the browser.

---

Compilation error

The file /app/gwt/core/server/DSPServiceImpl.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : GWT2Service cannot be resolved to a type

In /app/gwt/core/server/DSPServiceImpl.java (around line 174)

```
 import controllers.utils.DateUtil;
 import controllers.utils.DateUtil.Time;

 @GWT2ServicePath("/core/greet")

 public class DSPServiceImpl extends GWT2Service implements DSPService {
```

.
.
.
.
.

It may be a really newbie issue but could someone help me in case I should do something more?